# Export Gridview to Excel with EPPLus

Tags: asp.net, gridview, epplus

I am trying to export data from  datatable to Excel file using EPPlus, but nothing seems to work.
This is the code-

```
using (ExcelPackage xp = new ExcelPackage())
{
    ExcelWorksheet ws = xp.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(dt.TableName);

    int rowstart = 2;
    int colstart = 2;
    int rowend = rowstart;
    int colend = colstart + dt.Columns.Count;

    ws.Cells[rowstart, colstart, rowend, colend].Merge = true;
    ws.Cells[rowstart, colstart, rowend, colend].Value = dt.TableName;
    ws.Cells[rowstart, colstart, rowend, colend].Style.HorizontalAlignment = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelHorizontalAlignment.Center;
    ws.Cells[rowstart, colstart, rowend, colend].Style.Font.Bold = true;
    ws.Cells[rowstart, colstart, rowend, colend].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
    ws.Cells[rowstart, colstart, rowend, colend].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.LightGray);

    rowstart += 2;
    rowend = rowstart + dt.Rows.Count;
    ws.Cells[rowstart, colstart].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
    int i = 1;
    foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
    {
        i++;
        if (dc.DataType == typeof(decimal))
        ws.Column(i).Style.Numberformat.Format = "#0.00";
    }
    ws.Cells[ws.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();

    ws.Cells[rowstart, colstart, rowend, colend].Style.Border.Top.Style =
       ws.Cells[rowstart, colstart, rowend, colend].Style.Border.Bottom.Style =
       ws.Cells[rowstart, colstart, rowend, colend].Style.Border.Left.Style =
       ws.Cells[rowstart, colstart, rowend, colend].Style.Border.Right.Style = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;


    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=logs.xlsx");
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.BinaryWrite(xp.GetAsByteArray());
    Response.Close();
    HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

no exception is shown, code runs smoothly but no file is created.
I really dont know how to get what's happening behind this lines as its showing nothing. But I can see the cells in the sheet are filled.
I tried every other question and solution available on this site and other sites also. But nothing seems to work. so please dont only provide link to other questions and solutions.
Any other kind of advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you debug the code? Set a breakpoint? Does it reach the point where it writes the bytes to the response?

Comment: as you are saying,... I set a breakpoint on response.BinaryWrite(). and when I checked deeper,  response has some exceptions on output stream like read timeout, write timeout. how can I resolve that if this exception matters.

Comment: Can this exception occur  because of datatypes? I have a datetime column. can that through this error

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It works. `Response.BinaryWrite` does not work very well when downloading a file. And you haven't set the `content-length`

```
byte[] bin = xp.GetAsByteArray();

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-length", bin.Length.ToString());
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=logs.xlsx");
Response.OutputStream.Write(bin, 0, bin.Length);
Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: after trying your code.. got same exception, outputstream.length, outputstream.position notsupported exception. outputstream.readtimeout, outputstream.writetimeout. These exception are not shown through catch.

Comment: Is it because I have excel 2016?

Comment: No, that has nothing to do with is. Something else must be causing the problem because the above code works. Maybe you are doing something else that is not in your posted code?

Answer (score 0):

Probably Response.End() and "application/ms-excel" content type will solve your problem. Try the following code:

```
byte[] data= xp.GetAsByteArray();
Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=logs.xlsx; size=" + data.Length);    
Response.BinaryWrite(data);
Response.End();
```

Also if it's not working try to add the following code before:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
```

Comment: I have this same code which you are suggesting on another page.. and that is working for every possible file... The same code is not working on this page...where I want to export to excel..and I don't understand what is wrong with this page... As master page and everything else is same as another Page

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with help of another page who's job was just to take the file name and path and send to response.
If anyone stucks like me where you are doing everything right, things working on every other page but not where you want. So you can try this. No refresh or blinking will be done in this case. User wont feel that there was other page used at all.

CardLogs.aspx.cs

```
string filename = "logs_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy") + ".xlsx";
                FileInfo excelFile = new FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/" + filename));
                excel.SaveAs(excelFile);
                Session["fileName"] = excelFile.FullName;
                Response.Redirect("exportdata.aspx");
```

exportdata.aspx.cs file -

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Session["fileName"].ToString();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
        {
            Response.ContentType = ContentType;
            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));
            Response.WriteFile(filePath);
            Response.Flush();
            File.Delete(filePath);                
        }

    }
```