# How can I add a new row on top of excel sheet while exporting GridView rows to Excel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have a button which helps me export a Gridview to an excel file. Now along with exporting the GridView, I also want the button to add an
empty row on top of the excel file such that the Gridview only starts from the 2nd row. How can I do that? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

So far, I have this snippet which helps me export my Gridview perfectly.

```
 protected void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; 
    filename=Test.xls");
    Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
    System.IO.StringWriter stringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
    GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension. Then you have full control over the Excel sheet and you can do whatever you want with it like styling or create extra rows.

Comment: If you really want an extra header, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46906327/gridview-add-second-and-third-header-row-in-c-sharp

Comment: @VDWWD You were right! It was just an HTML page with .xls extension. So I was looking into EPPlus and it definitely is easier to manipulate basic operations like adding rows, formatting cells etc but what about the Gridview? My main goal is to have the Gridview data in excel first, then manipulate it. Most resources on the web suggest what I did above but clearly, that doesn't work for my case. So when you say use libraries, are you suggesting me to write the data of Gridview into excel file instead of exporting?

Comment: You have to bind data to the GridView, like a DataTable, List etc. You can bind that data directly into EPPlus. Then export that Excel file to the client. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53966615/5836671